# sidekiq mongoid 4 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, mongoid4

I am working with rails4 monogid and sidekiq , I am unable to start(exec) sidekiq with the following command

bundle exec sidekiq

following is the stack trace

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/actionview-4.1.4/lib/action_view/helpers/debug_helper.rb:29:in `debug'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:110:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:64:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/ratna/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
/home/ratna/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/ratna/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/ratna/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/ratna/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
/home/ratna/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
/home/ratna/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/ratna/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
/home/ratna/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
/home/ratna/ratna/Projects/Vrcommand/Dec/dec10/vrcommand/config/environment.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/sidekiq-3.3.0/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:236:in `boot_system'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/sidekiq-3.3.0/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:50:in `run'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/gems/sidekiq-3.3.0/bin/sidekiq:8:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<main>'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/ratna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vrcommand/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error , can anyone please help me .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by downgrading the sidekiq version to 3.1.x , I am getting issues with 3.2.x